# Regarding changing bash file and making new directory for mongodb

Tags: macos, mongodb, command, installation

I am trying to play around with mongodb using osx, and for doing so I am required to create a directory using the following inside the directory of my mongodb exe

```
mkdir /data/db
```

however when I attempt to do so, my command prompt return the following

```
$ mkdir /data/db
mkdir: /data: No such file or directory
```

currently my mongodb exe are not command line enabled, that is it is not in the path of the bash, does anyone know how to make the mongodb program global?

thanks in advance

added
so I tried both adding the bash file, and

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
$ mkdir -p /data/db
```

simply typing

```
$ mongod
```

still doesn't work, I have to type the following

```
$ ./mongod
```

but it gives the following

```
$ ./mongod
./mongod --help for help and startup options
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.558 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1042 port=27017           dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=unknown20c9d0b97f55.att.net
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] 
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.5
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] git version:    a2ddc68ba7c9cee17bfe69ed840383ec3506602b
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-2.10gen.cc     10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-   1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] options: {}
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to     create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance   already running?, terminating
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 dbexit: 
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Thu Jul 18 13:27:37.559 dbexit: really exiting now
```

edit 2:

tried

```
sudo chown 'myusername' /data/db
```

neither 
    sudo ./mongod 
or
    ./mongod

worked

edit 3:

```
$ ./mongod
./mongod --help for help and startup options
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.144 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1550 port=27017     dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=unknown20c9d0b97f55.att.net
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] 
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.5
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] git version: a2ddc68ba7c9cee17bfe69ed840383ec3506602b
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-2.10gen.cc 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] options: {}
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 dbexit: 
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...   
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Thu Jul 18 14:11:35.145 dbexit: really exiting now



$ sudo ./mongod
./mongod --help for help and startup options
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.450 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1552 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=unknown20c9d0b97f55.att.net
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.451 [initandlisten] 
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.451 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.451 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.5
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.451 [initandlisten] git version: a2ddc68ba7c9cee17bfe69ed840383ec3506602b
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.451 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-2.10gen.cc 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.451 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.451 [initandlisten] options: {}
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.451 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.451 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [initandlisten] now exiting
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 dbexit: 
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.489 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.500 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.505 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.505 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.505 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.506 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Jul 18 14:11:43.506 dbexit: really exiting now
```

edit 4:

```
$ sudo killall mongod
Password:

$ sudo rm -rf /data/db
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db
$ sudo chown xxxxx/data/db
usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
       chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
$ ./mongod
./mongod --help for help and startup options
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.047 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=417 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=unknown20c9d0b97f55.att.net
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.047 [initandlisten] 
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.047 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.047 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.5
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.047 [initandlisten] git version: a2ddc68ba7c9cee17bfe69ed840383ec3506602b
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.047 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-2.10gen.cc 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.047 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.047 [initandlisten] options: {}
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.110 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.110 dbexit: 
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.110 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.110 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.110 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.110 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.110 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.110 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.110 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.119 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.119 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.119 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Thu Jul 18 14:27:04.119 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: Use mkdir -p /data/db to create any intervening directories along the path.

Comment: If you create the directory via sudo, it ends up being a directory that only root can write to. Either use chown to change its owner to yourself, or run mongod as root so it can write to /data/db

Comment: $ sudo chown `id -u` /data/db? is id my computer id, and what is -u?

Comment: "id -u" is a command that returns your own user id. But you need your alphanumeric user name.  You get that with `whoami`.  So the full command would be `sudo chown \`whoami\` /data/db`.

Comment: $ sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
$ mkdir -p /data/db

so currently I tried both, I think i am just going to recompress, and create the datapath again, would that work, or do I have to delete the old datapath I created

Comment: If the directory /data/db is there, you simply have to make sure that it is owned by the correct user – yourself.  That is done by the command I mentioned last.  Nothing else should be required.

Comment: so i tried that, but now sudo ./mongod return me the same error, originally sudo ./mongod worked, is there anyway i can redo the entire process?

Comment: you can do `sudo rm -rf /data/db; sudo mkdir -p /data/db; sudo chown yourusername /data/db` and then run mongod (without sudo).

Comment: yup, did exactly that,    sudo rm -rf /data/db; sudo mkdir -p /data/db; sudo chown xxxx /data/db ------- and i run./mongod, then the same error appeared

Comment: I'm at my wit's end then. After the commands I just gave you the error message you showed cannot happen, or so I would think. I would have to actually sit at your system to figure out what is going on.

Comment: that's ok, i post the error message i got so far, so if you are interested you can take a look, but thank you so much for your patience and help I really appreciated it

Comment: Well, what happened is that a mongod was already running, then you deleted the /data/db directory underneath that mongod, and now it is still running and you are trying to launch a second one.  What you should do now is `killall mongod`, and then the sequence of sudo commands that I gave you previously, and then start mongod again.

Comment: this is what i got
$ killall mongod
No matching processes belonging to you were found

Comment: Oh, then it should be `sudo killall mongod`

Comment: what is really interesting is that ./mongod now works, but sudo ./mongod still receives error, i posted the error above,

Comment: When you run mongod, you have a process running that tries to lock the database to itself.  You cannot launch mongod again once you have a single instance of it running.

Comment: yes, so if i restart the computer, and create the data/db again, ./mongod should work, but it doesn't, instead if I immediately type sudo ./mongod, the database will connect, which is kind of odd

Comment: You have to decide whether you want to run mongod under your own user or under sudo, and then run only that command. Don't try to launch it several times.

Comment: In your most recent edit, it shows that you did not type the chown command correctly, there needs to be a space between the user name and the path.

Comment: lol, you are right, it actually worked, thank you so much, btw is kill the properly exit command instead of directly control z ?

Comment: The proper way to shut down the mongod process is to connect via the mongo shell, and then do db.shutdownServer(). Control-Z does not actually kill the process, just suspends it.

Answer (score -1):

Can you add it to your bashrc?

```
cd 
nano .bashrc
mongodb="path_To_mongodb.exe" ## add this to bashrc, save and quit. Then restart terminal.
```

Make sure there no spaces. Replace "path_To_mongodb.exe" with the actual path to your exe. Make sure it's in the right file, and saved, and terminal restarted, and if you're trying it in a script, expand the variables by adding

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bashrc
```

to the start of the script.

Comment: I tried mongodb="path_To_mongodb.exe" but command line still does not recognize $ mongodb
-bash: mongodb: command not found

Comment: yes i tried, mongodb="Downloads/xxx/xxx/mongodb/bin", but it seems like it wouldn't recognize it